# Backbone.js Backbone.wrapError function

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

This questions was about Backbone 0.9.2

**Since upgrading to Backbone 0.9.10 we've chosen to override Backbone.sync instead and it works like a charm.**

- **December 2012** - (v0.9.9) Backbone.wrapError has been removed.
- **February 2013** - It looks like WrapError will be brought back in the next version of Backbone, but overriding backbone.sync is the way to go.

(sorry for the long read)

I'm modifying the Backbone.wrapError function and I'm baffling by a line. I know what the line does, but not WHY it is necessary.

```
  resp = model === originalModel ? resp : model;
```

- resp ends up being the textStatus/errorType ie: "error" "timeout"
  "parse error"
- model is the XHR request object
- originalModel is a reference to the Backbone.Model instance which ultimately called this function

I have a good grasp on what Backbone.wrapError does, what it returns and how it is used but I can't seem to understand the purpose of the above line.

---

Backbone's documentation states that wrapError will 'Wrap an optional error callback with a fallback error event,' which is true. Additionally, I've learned is that Backbone.wrapError is called 4 times in the library from within the fetch, save, destroy and reset functions in order to ensure that AJAX errors do not go unnoticed by the library. For example, if an AJAX error callback is passed into the fetch method it will be executed with a few parameters passed along, if not, the model will trigger an error event with the same few parameters passed along.

Sample call:

```
options.error = Backbone.wrapError(options.error, model, options);
```

Backbone.wrapError:

```
  Backbone.wrapError = function(onError, originalModel, options) {
    return function(model, resp) {
      resp = model === originalModel ? resp : model;
      if (onError) {
        onError(originalModel, resp, options);
      } else {
        originalModel.trigger('error', originalModel, resp, options);
      }
    };
  };
```

The problem that arises with this line (`resp = model === originalModel ? resp : model;`) is that model and resp correspond to the first 2 parameters within the jQuery/Zepto error callback parameter list. The first problem I have is with the naming of these parameters (model, response), because while debugging I've seen that those 2 parameters are `jqXHR/xhr` and `textStatus/errorType`. The textStatus/errorType parameters usually end up being "error" but (according to the docs) can also be "timeout" "parse error" etc. The comparison of `model === originalModel` makes no sense to me. A hard comparison on an XHR object and a Backbone.Model instance will always fail, and `model` will be stored into `response` (resp), which is fine because the `model` is actually the XHR response object... this line just seems pointless to me, but I went ahead and included it in my modified wrapError method.

Because `model === originalModel` always evaluates to false, the line seems to be an elaborate version of resp = model; which is useless, because you could just remove the line entirely and the `model` parameter could be passed into `originalModel.trigger('error', originalModel, resp, options);` instead of `resp`.

**Is there any instance where `model === originalModel` could possibly evaluate to true?**

**Anybody with more experience in Backbone.js, AJAX have an answer/explanation of why this line is necessary?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR/CLIFFS:**

The weird little line below is used to determine weather the error callback was triggered from a failed validation at the model level, or from a failed AJAX call from the fetch, save, or destroy methods (which all call Backbone.sync). If the failure is from validation, it does not change the resp variable because resp should already hold useful information returned by validate (such as an errors array or a string about the error). If the failure is from a bad AJAX request, the XHR object is stored into resp because the XHR is the most informative item available. Unfortunately, the XHR is passed into this function as model and Backbone documentation fails to point out that this parameter does not always represent a model. Resp is meant to hold useful response information about the error(s), and is sent to the error callback or a thrown error event.

---

Okay. I learned some things about this weird line.

```
resp = model === originalModel ? resp : model;
```

In Backbone there are AJAX errors and Validation errors. Conveniently, Backbone funnels both errors into the same function -- the AJAX error callback. The problem is that the arguments passed into these functions are inconsistent. When there is an AJAX error an XHR object is available, but not during a validation error.

- *If there is no callback present, Backbone will throw and 'error' event with the same parameters that would have been passed into the error callback. (line 7 and 9 below).*

After a successful AJAX request, your JSON data can be optionally passed through the model's validate function. In Backbone, the validate function `should return false or nothing at all when there are no errors`. When there ARE errors, it is typical to return an array such as `['invalid username', 'password too long', 'etc...']` Anything returned from validate (usually an error messages array) is passed into the 'wrapped' error callback as the `resp` parameter **and the model itself is passed as `model`**!

The _validate function is a bit sloppy and has multiple return statements, but when validation fails, line 9 is hit. Line 9 of the `_validate` function passes `this` (the model), `error` (returned from the models validate method), `options` (ajax options, success, error, timeout etc). This differs from an AJAX error which will pass in `xhr` (xmlhttprequest object), `errorType` ('error' 'timeout' 'parse error' etc), `options` (ajax options).

```
validate error:   error(model, validate_return_value, options)
    ajax error:   error(xhr, errorType, options)

1   _validate: function(attrs, options) {
2     if (options.silent || !this.validate) return true;
3     attrs = _.extend({}, this.attributes, attrs);
4     var error = this.validate(attrs, options);
5     if (!error) return true;
6     if (options && options.error) {
7*       options.error(this, error, options);
8     } else {
9       this.trigger('error', this, error, options);
10    }
11    return false;
12  }
```

The strange line of code above is necessary because, this one function handles errors from 2 different methods. AJAX and Validation. Those 2 send it different parameters, so this is meant to normalize them and throw events with consistent parameter lists.

`When a validation error occurs, the model does not change` so the `model` that is passed into the error callback **is** exactly equal to the `originalModel`. The purpose of the `resp` parameter is to hold information about the error itself. When there's an AJAX error, 'timeout' 'parse error' or 'error' are simply not as informative as the XHR object.

**That weird little line determines weather the error callback was accessed from `_validate` or through a normal AJAX error such as a 404.** When it is accessed from validate, `resp` is the value returned from validate. It should be informative, and useful data for the front-end templates to display. When the resulting error is from a HTTP error, the most useful information about that error is the XHR object which is passed into this function as the MODEL parameter.

A hopefully simplified approach to the wrapError and validate functions

```
   Backbone.wrapError = function(ajax_error_callback, model_or_xhr, ajax_options) {
      return function(model_or_xhr, error_info) {
        if there was an ajax error, error_info = the xhr object
        if there was a validation error, error_info = whatever was returned from validate
        if there's an error callback {
          run the error callback with (the original model, error_info, ajax_options)  as parameters
        if there is not an error callback
          throw an event called 'error' with (the original model, error_info, ajax_options) as parameters
        }
      };
    };
```

original:

```
   Backbone.wrapError = function(onError, originalModel, options) {
      return function(model, resp) {
        resp = model === originalModel ? resp : model;
        if (onError) {
    *      onError(originalModel, resp, options);
        } else {
          originalModel.trigger('error', originalModel, resp, options);
        }
      };
    };
```

The * shows that error callback called from here